# Remove/delete a custom menu from a Google Doc with Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

Is it possible to remove a custom menu from a Google Doc?

It seems pretty simple with GoogleSheets (see code below from this [blog post](http://apps-script-google.blogspot.com/2015/03/custom-menu-create-delete.html)):

```
function RemoveMenu1() {
     var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
     ss.removeMenu('Custom Menu');
}
```

I've tried this below, but .removeMenu doesn't seem to work still. Any ideas?

```
DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().removeMenu('Custom');
```

Thanks!

Comment: It's not in the documentation.  If you want a new feature go ask for it.

Comment: Always useful to consult the documentation. `removemenu` [Doc](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#removemenuname) and there is an example supplied. The part to focus on is that this removes a menu that was added by `addMenu(name, subMenus)` AND the name argument should ("Custom") must have the same value as the corresponding call to addMenu(name, subMenus). Is that the case with your code?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Looks like someone already asked about modifying and deleting menus in their Issue Tracker. I'll star the request, and follow-up if I learn of anything new. Someone mentioned you can reCreate that menu with another set of SubMenus, but I'm not sure how that works yet. In any case, thanks again!
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37405264

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to remove a custom menu from a Google Doc?

No, it is not possible. As you can read on [Document docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document#body), there is no method to remove a custom menu.

Optionally, you can write a feature request on [Google Issue Tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker) so the engineers can consider your petition.